# cakephp habtm relationship (saving data)

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, relationship

Question related to HABTM has been posted in some good numbers on stackoverflow but I am still looking for a solution to my problem.

I am creating an application that allows for creation of topics based on a particular subcategory.
While adding a topic the user is asked for tags (on the same form). Now when the user has finished adding tags to the topic on the click of Add button the topic is successfully added but tags are not.

I have created the join table for both topics and tags as `tbl_tags_topics.` (as defined in the conventions of cakephp) and defined the 'hasAndBelongsToMany' array properly in both the models of topics and tags.

What steps am I missing now.?

I have one more question related to this but I will post it when I will be able to send tags related to a topic successfully to the database. (the functionality is similar to that of stackoverflow's tags adding and attaching)

any help is greatly appreciated., also let me know of any good tutorials on HABTM if you find one.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Security Component?

Comment: no, I am not using any Security Component right now. It(Auth) will be implemented when this(HABTM) feature is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of Mr. [Stornvig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50685/anderstornvig), I was able to solve my problem. Here is the [link](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/full_cakephp_application_part_5/) that describes the complete procedure of how to achieve such functionality in cakephp. This is an awesome tutorial for learning more about HABTM relationship.

For version 1.3 I found out this technique to be useful. Here are the steps:

after defining the HABTM relationship array in both the models

create your form like this

```
echo $form->create('Job');
echo $form->input('title');
echo $form->input('description');
echo $form->input('location');
echo $form->input('Category');//note the caps and single plural
$form->end('Submit');
```

and then in the controller add method simply use the

> saveAll($this->data)

and the join table will be populated with the required records also.

[**more info**](http://cakeqs.org/eng/questions/view/how_do_i_add_multiple_categories_to_jobs_and_save_the_form_data)

Answer (score 5):

When you save one of the fields, you pass parameters like that :

```
$this->Model->save(
    'Model' => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'one random field)
);
```

If you have tags, which is a HABTM, you could do the following :

```
$this->Model->save(
    'Model' => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'one random field'),
    'Tag' => array('Tag' => array(1))
);
```

However there's a problem with this native feature, it's that every time you save your object, you need to pass **every** tag to the saved array. Otherwise, they'll all be removed before to be readded.

However you can find on bakery, a plugin called [extended associations](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/add-delete-habtm-behavior).

Using it, you would do :

```
$this->Model->habtmAdd('Tag', 1, 1);
```

Where the first "1" is the model's object id. And the second is the tag's object id.

And to remove a tag :

```
$this->Post->habtmDelete('Tag', 1, 1);
```

Comment: I added the "extend_associations.php" and now i'm receiving the follow warning: "Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 314]". I'm using cakephp 2.

Comment: @matheusvmbruno Same here, have you solved this issue?

Comment: @matheusvmbruno Ok, I just solved the problem. I guess it has to do with new cakephp conventions. 1. The reference to the behavior class in the $actsAs attribute in your model has to be wrapped in an array (that's why there's an invalid argument for the foreach loop, because it expects an array). 2. There will be other warnings, which suggest to change the extend_associations.php file name to the one according to the value which you passed into the $actsAs attribute (ExtendAssociations.php for instance).